# Dynamically added CheckBoxes to a CheckBoxList not showing Text

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, checkbox

Following is my code for adding CheckBoxes dynamically to a CheckBoxList:

```
foreach (WCore.CategoryFields cat in Global.getCategories())
{
        CheckBox c = new CheckBox();
        c.Text = cat.CategoryId;
        c.Tag = cat.CategoryName;
        if (ints != null)
        {
            if (ints.Contains(c.Tag))
               Invoke(new Action(()=>checkedListBox1.Items.Add(c, true)));
            else
               Invoke(new Action(()=>checkedListBox1.Items.Add(c, false)));
        }
        else
            Invoke(new Action(()=>checkedListBox1.Items.Add(c, false)));
}
```

The problem is that whenever I run this code, the checkboxes are added but not with the text. Like this:
[image]

I tried to debug it and then I found that CheckBox instance 'c' is getting Text but not showing it.

See here:
[image]

Please tell me what's wrong going on in this code?

**UPDATE**

Please note that I can't use it like this:

```
Invoke(new Action(()=>checkedListBox1.Controls.Add(c)));
```

because its better to use panel instead of CheckBoxList then.
Also I want two values one shown as text and other hidden as value for each CheckBox in CheckBoxList

**UPDATE 2**

Code to get selected items:

```
List<string> SelInts = new List<string>();
foreach (ListBoxItem c in checkedListBox1.SelectedItems)
{
        SelInts.Add(c.Tag.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I guess you mean you want to get the `checked items` not the `selected items`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (WCore.CategoryFields cat in Global.getCategories()){
    ListBoxItem c = new ListBoxItem;
    c.Text = cat.CategoryId;
    c.Tag = cat.CategoryName;
    if (ints != null)
    {
        if (ints.Contains(c.Tag))
           Invoke(new Action(()=>checkedListBox1.Items.Add(c, true)));
        else
           Invoke(new Action(()=>checkedListBox1.Items.Add(c, false)));
    }
    else
        Invoke(new Action(()=>checkedListBox1.Items.Add(c, false)));
}
//Add this class somewhere in your form class or beside it
public class ListBoxItem {
   public string Text {get;set;}
   public object Tag {get;set;}
   public override string ToString(){
      return Text;
   }
}
```

I doubt that somehow your `CheckBox` can't be displayed as a string although it should show the `System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox` instead of blanks.

Comment: But VS is showing this error `The type or namespace name 'ListBoxItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. I think you are telling me the answer for WPF. I am developing this app in pure WinForms

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva No, I have a class called `ListBoxItem`, you should add it some where in your form class or beside it.

Comment: Oh m sorry. I was in hurry, so didn't read your code completely. Will try it and then tell you.

Comment: Thanks this worked. But another problem is coming. When I try to get selected items on a button click, its returning only first selected item. Not All. Check UPDATE 2 in my question for its code.

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva Could you make it clear on what button you used? Your code doesn't return anything so it's a little confused to me.

Comment: @KingKong its a normal WinForms button

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva do you really mean `Selected items` because I guess you mean `Checked items`, you are using a `CheckedListBox`, so checked items would be better for specifying choices. If you really mean `selected items`, you should be sure that the `SelectionMode` set to `MultiSimple` or `MultiExtended` and there are more than 1 item selected before you click the button.

Comment: Hey, that's correct. I changed `SelectedItems` to  `CheckedItems` and it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to do

```
Invoke(new Action(()=>checkedListBox1.Items.Add(c.Text, true)));
```

instead of

```
Invoke(new Action(()=>checkedListBox1.Items.Add(c, true)));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps u can do only declare the listitem and set the name and value

```
     ListItem item = new ListItem();
     item.Text = "text on checkbox";
     item.Value = "Value of checkbox";
     item.Enabled = true;
    // add to the current checkbox list that u using 
     
     CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(item);
```